# Error handling in stored procedure when calling with wrong parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to handle failures in my first written stored procedure. My goal is to have a variable which is default set to zero and if any failure happens it will increase to 1. Thereafter I will do a check on this variable if it is set to 1 and output a simple text.

This is what I've got so far, but if I'm trying out and call the procedure with 2 varchars instead of an Integer, I don't get my message.

Any hint what I am doing wrong ?

```sql
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS changePrice;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE 
    changePrice(IN categorie VARCHAR(30), IN factor INT) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE stat_var INT DEFAULT 0;
   
    BEGIN         
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
        BEGIN
            SET stat_var = 1;
        END;
        
        UPDATE 
            Artikel
        SET
            Einzelpreis = (Einzelpreis * (factor / 100))
        WHERE
            Kategorie = categorie;
    END;
    
    IF stat_var = 1 THEN
        SELECT 'Fehler MOOOOOOOP';
    END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;

CALL changePrice('Metallwaren', 'a');
```

Comment: I would expect "Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'factor' at row .. " referencing the `CALL changePrice('Metallwaren', 'a');` row.

Comment: But the error you are seeing ("ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: 'a' for column 'factor' at row 1") is caught earlier.

Answer (score 0):

1. EXIT HANDLER is defined for nested BEGIN-END block, and hence when SQLEXCEPTION occures then the code flow is exited from this bliock, not from the whole procedure.
2. Local variable is defined within the BEGIN-END block only, and it will be destroyed after SP execution finished. YOU must use user-defined variable which is connection-specific and won't be destroyed.
3. You provide string-type value for a parameter which is defined as INT. This will cause an error during parametrs type check. SP shouldn't execute, handler code shouldn't fire.

Comment: Ah ok. I now tried to call the procedure with correct types like ´´´changePrice('Metallwaren', 'a');´´´ and changed the row name 'Einzelpreis' into a non existing row name and it worked, the Message was fired.